# How to change solution? (codecademy, median, python3.4)

Tags: python, median

I use python 3.4 for coding. Codecademy editor doesn't accept my solution. Task is to write a function to find the median of a list.

My code:

```
def median(nums):
    a = sorted(nums)

    if len(a)==1:
        return a[0]
    elif len(a) % 2 != 0:
        return a[int((len(a) - 1)/2)]
    else:
        return (a[int((len(a))/2)] + a[int(((len(a))/2) - 1)])/2
```

So, how to change my code that it will be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information that you have provided so far, I believe it is probably a problem of integer division. In the case when there are an even number of elements in the list, you have to take the average. In python3.4, `/` does float division but in python2, it does integer division. So you should modifying your line to the following (`2.0` instead of `2`):

```
return (a[int((len(a))/2)] + a[int(((len(a))/2) - 1)]) / 2.0
```

This will force python to do float division instead of integer division